# Oracle table dynamic partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a java code to upload data from oracle tables every 15mins based from the INSERT_DATETIME field (timestamp). I need to partition the tables based on 15minute intervals. is there a way to do it dynamically (partitioning). I'm using oracle11g in oracle SQL developer.

A sample of one of the tables I created and I want to add a partition:

```
CREATE TABLE "PV_TNPM"."TEJAS_CARD_REPORT" 
(   "INSERT_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"IPADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"PRODUCTCODE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"LCTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CARDTYPELABEL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"SOFTWAREVERSION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 32768 NEXT 1523712 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 1017
PCTINCREASE 50 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

I'm not familiar with SQL as the above code is just generated from the table I created. Any help is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the table with [interval partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#VLDBG00221):

```
CREATE TABLE TEJAS_CARD_REPORT
(
    "INSERT_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME"         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "IPADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCTCODE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "LCTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CARDTYPELABEL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SOFTWAREVERSION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
) partition by range(insert_datetime) interval (interval '15' minute)
(
    partition initial_partition values less than (date '2000-01-01')
);
```

Partitions are dynamically created as data is inserted.

```
insert into tejas_card_report(insert_datetime) values (timestamp '2000-01-01 00:14:00');
insert into tejas_card_report(insert_datetime) values (timestamp '2000-01-01 00:29:00');
insert into tejas_card_report(insert_datetime) values (timestamp '2000-10-11 00:00:00');

SQL> select partition_name, high_value from dba_tab_partitions where table_name = 'TEJAS_CARD_REPORT';

PARTITION_NAME       HIGH_VALUE
-------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_P21516           TIMESTAMP' 2000-10-11 00:15:00'
SYS_P21515           TIMESTAMP' 2000-01-01 00:30:00'
SYS_P21514           TIMESTAMP' 2000-01-01 00:15:00'
INITIAL_PARTITION    TIMESTAMP' 2000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

On an unrelated note, avoid `TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"`.  You almost never want to store any user or application data in the SYSTEM tablespace.